# Highlighting dates in multiple color using Mat datepicker

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

I've two set of date's which needs to be highlighted in orange and red color using Angular matrial date picker.

For eg, user input will be like this,

```
const dateInOrange = [1,5,10,20]
const dateInRed = [10,22,27]
```

So Far, I could able to highlight the date's which are orange color but red is not getting highlighted.

Please help below is my link to stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-class-filter-nyxgww?file=app/datepicker-date-class-example.ts

Comment: You have return statement only for orange class, check line 68

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-class-filter-aactjv

your orange is fully so always return there i took one more if as checking selected

```
private _setupClassFunction() {
  this.dateClass = (d: Date) => {
  let selected = false;      
  if (this._orangeDatesArray) {
    selected = this._orangeDatesArray.some(
      (item: Date) =>
        item.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear() &&
        item.getDate() === d.getDate() &&
        item.getMonth() === d.getMonth()
    );
    if(selected){
      return selected ? "example-custom-date--orange-class " : undefined;
    }
    else if (this._redDatesArray) {            
      selected = this._redDatesArray.some(
        (item: Date) =>
          item.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear() &&
          item.getDate() === d.getDate() &&
          item.getMonth() === d.getMonth()
      );
      return selected ? "example-custom-date--red-class " : undefined;          
    }
  }  
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use the this one function at both places.

```
private _setupClassFunction() {
    this.dateClass = (d: Date) => {
      let selected = false;
      var className = "";
      selected = this._redDatesArray.some(
        (item: Date) =>
          item.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear() &&
          item.getDate() === d.getDate() &&
          item.getMonth() === d.getMonth()
      );
      className = selected ? "example-custom-date--red-class " : "";

      selected = this._orangeDatesArray.some(
        (item: Date) =>
          item.getFullYear() === d.getFullYear() &&
          item.getDate() === d.getDate() &&
          item.getMonth() === d.getMonth()
      );
      className+= selected ? "example-custom-date--orange-class " : "";
      return className;
    };
```

Cagri's solution is also a great one.